# App update stuck in 'in review' status in google play console

Tags: android, google-play-console

I uploaded the second version of My App in Google play Console but it has been showing "in review" status since last week. I haven't got any warning emails either. Don't know what went wrong.

Comment: My record is three weeks. Lately every update takes around 24 hours. Someone should remind Google that we are selling digital products.

Comment: Review after covid is taking a lot longer than expected. You should wait until you get any response.

Comment: Can we contact support for such delay and is there any way to make this process faster from our side?

Comment: Did you get any answer at the End ? If yes, how long did you wait in total ?

Comment: Its been a week, my app new update status also stuck in review, is they any support team for play console  or any email we can contact?

Comment: @SoubhagyaSwain Could You tell us what happened with you?

Comment: @Jabbar it got published after 6 weeks of wait.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to wait, one time it took 1 month.

Comment: You definitely don't need to wait for this amount of time. 1 month indicates your app has been missed and slipped down their pile, and you either need to cancel the submission and re-submit or directly contact Google and alert them.

Answer (score 2):

You have to wait, it would take minimum 7 days or more.